# Jupyter Notebook SPSS integration

Tags: jupyter-notebook, spss

To run statistical tests on my data, I use SPSS and call it from a Jupyter Notebook. The integration works fine. I wondered, if there is a better way to display the results in a jupyter notebook. The tables seem to be messed up and figures wont show. Is it possible to output in a SPSS window from a Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SPSS Model Visualizations for Jupyter [1], but if that is what you are already doing, then open and issue on the project? How are you calling SPSS from your Notebook?

[1] https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/spss-visualization.html?linkInPage=true